# Converting hex colors to span

Tags: php, html

so basically I'm trying to find the correct regex to convert hex colors to span. for example:

```
#FF0000Hello#00FF00There
<span style="color: #FF0000">Hello</span><span style="color: #00FF00">There</span>
```

Comment: And where is the code that you tried? Which of the OP is input data and which is Desired result? It is impossible to tell what exactly are you trying to achieve

Comment: Question seems clear (btw, there is no question), but doesn't show any effort from your side to solve your issue. If you already have code, please paste it here and tell us where it fails so we can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a hint:

```
$x = '#FF0000Hello#00FF00There';

$str = preg_replace('/(#[0-9,A-F]{6})(\w*)/', '<span style="color: $1;">$2</span>', $x);
```